# How to do swipe action in QT for android

Tags: android, qt

I am trying to create an image viewer app with slide show. When the user clicks on the play button, the viewer starts to show images with slide show in another window. When the the user clicks on the stop button, the viewer stops to show images. This part is successfully done.

But the remaining part is not finished successfully. I suppose that when the user swipe left on the slide show screen, it will return to the main page screen, and when the user swipe right on the main page screen, it will return to the slide show screen. But my code fails to do such actions. The screen is just no response with one finger, but work with three fingers. I just knew that the Qt::SwipeGesture as part of the QGestureRecognizer registers with three fingers instead of one. Please help me.

Main page screen

[image: Main screen]

Slide show screen

[image: slide show screen]

Code:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include "showpic.h"
#include <QBasicTimer>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QSwipeGesture>
#include <QGestureEvent>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    bool event(QEvent *event);
    void swipeTriggered(QSwipeGesture *gesture);
    bool gestureEvent(QGestureEvent *event);

private slots:        
    void tick();
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_3_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QFileSystemModel *model;
    QString filesPath;
    ShowPic *showpic;
    QStringList filenames;
    QStringList::const_iterator m_imageIt;
    QTimer m_timer;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

showpic.h

```
#ifndef SHOWPIC_H
#define SHOWPIC_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QSwipeGesture>
#include <QGestureEvent>

namespace Ui {
class ShowPic;
}

class ShowPic : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ShowPic(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ShowPic();

public:
    void addPixmap(const QPixmap &pixmap);
    bool event(QEvent *event);
    void swipeTriggered(QSwipeGesture *gesture);
    bool gestureEvent(QGestureEvent *event);

private:
    Ui::ShowPic *ui;
};

#endif // SHOWPIC_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include<QFileDialog>
#include<QFileSystemModel>
#include<QStringList>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QTime>
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QSwipeGesture>
#include <QGestureEvent>
#include <QEvent>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    filenames.append("/mnt/m_internal_storage/test/apple.jpg");
    filenames.append("/mnt/m_internal_storage/test/grape.jpg");
    filenames.append("/mnt/m_internal_storage/test/lemon.jpg");

    showpic = NULL;
    m_timer.setInterval(1000);
    connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(tick()));
    grabGesture(Qt::SwipeGesture);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *event)
{
     if (event->type() == QEvent::Gesture)
         return gestureEvent(static_cast<QGestureEvent*>(event));
     return QWidget::event(event);
}

void MainWindow::swipeTriggered(QSwipeGesture *gesture)
 {
     if (gesture->state() == Qt::GestureFinished) {
         if (gesture->horizontalDirection() == QSwipeGesture::Right){
             if(showpic != NULL){
                 showpic->show();
             }
         }
     }
 }

bool MainWindow::gestureEvent(QGestureEvent *event)
 {
     if (QGesture *swipe = event->gesture(Qt::SwipeGesture))
         swipeTriggered(static_cast<QSwipeGesture *>(swipe));

     return true;
 }

void MainWindow::tick(){
    showpic->addPixmap(*m_imageIt);
    m_imageIt ++;
    if(m_imageIt == filenames.end()){
        m_timer.stop();
        m_imageIt = filenames.begin();
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked() //play button
{

    m_imageIt = filenames.begin();

    if(!filenames.isEmpty() && showpic == NULL){
            showpic = new ShowPic();            
    }

    if(!filenames.isEmpty() && !showpic->isVisible()){ // initial click

        showpic->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
        showpic->show();

    }

    if(!filenames.isEmpty())
        m_timer.start();

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()  //stop button
{
       m_timer.stop();
}
```

showpic.cpp

```
#include "showpic.h"
#include "ui_showpic.h"
#include <QGestureEvent>

ShowPic::ShowPic(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ShowPic)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(new QGraphicsScene);
    ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(ui->graphicsView);
    this->setLayout(ui->horizontalLayout);
    grabGesture(Qt::SwipeGesture);
}

ShowPic::~ShowPic()
{
    delete ui;
}


bool ShowPic::event(QEvent *event)
{
     if (event->type() == QEvent::Gesture)
         return gestureEvent(static_cast<QGestureEvent*>(event));
     return QWidget::event(event);
}

void ShowPic::swipeTriggered(QSwipeGesture *gesture)
 {
     if (gesture->state() == Qt::GestureFinished) {
         if (gesture->horizontalDirection() == QSwipeGesture::Left)
             this->hide();
     }
 }

bool ShowPic::gestureEvent(QGestureEvent *event)
 {
     if (QGesture *swipe = event->gesture(Qt::SwipeGesture))
         swipeTriggered(static_cast<QSwipeGesture *>(swipe));

     return true;
 }

void ShowPic::addPixmap(const QPixmap &pixmap){

    ui->graphicsView->setScene(new QGraphicsScene);   
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->addPixmap(pixmap);
    ui->graphicsView->fitInView(ui->graphicsView->scene()->itemsBoundingRect() ,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
}
```

Besides, someone told me that some part of my program causes memory leak problem, which occurs at `ui->graphicsView->setScene(new QGraphicsScene);`, but if I make it as `ui->graphicsView->scene()->clear();` before adding pixmap, the image scene will become larger continuously when adding images. At the moment, I don't know how to fix this memory leak problem.

Comment: The best and safe approach for Qt Android is to use QML for UI, write your screens in QML while your backend logic in C++